# CXF and optional entity parameters

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I'm using Apache CXF as JAX-RS implementation and I have a problem with optional "entity parameters". Take a look at this piece of code:

```java
@Path("/")
public class myClass {

    @PUT
    @Path("/{p1}/something/{p2}/something/{p3}/something/{p4}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    Response updateStuff(
                    @PathParam("p1") String p1,
                    @PathParam("p2") Long p2,
                    @PathParam("p3") String p3,
                    @PathParam("p4") Long p4,
                    MyEntity entity); 
}
```

If entity is not null, everything works fine.

However I want to handle requests with empty body. I would expect, that in such case entity would be null. But it is not true. It seems that CXF can't find my method if body is null. In the logs I can find warning about empty message body (from AbstractJAXBProvider) and that's all.

I also tried to overload updateStuff method:

```java
@Path("/")
public class myClass {

    @PUT
    @Path("/{p1}/something/{p2}/something/{p3}/something/{p4}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    Response updateStuff(
                    @PathParam("p1") String p1,
                    @PathParam("p2") Long p2,
                    @PathParam("p3") String p3,
                    @PathParam("p4") Long p4,
                    MyEntity entity); 

    @PUT
    @Path("/{p1}/something/{p2}/something/{p3}/something/{p4}")
    Response updateStuff(
                    @PathParam("p1") String p1,
                    @PathParam("p2") Long p2,
                    @PathParam("p3") String p3,
                    @PathParam("p4") Long p4); 
}
```

But it didn't work either.

Do you have any ideas how to handle null entites parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you webservice `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` the body can't be null.
But you can handle this having a `@Provider` to read `MyEntity` object.

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class XMLReader implements MessageBodyReader<MyEntity>{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method overloading, as in your example, works (tested in Apache-cxf 3.0), but the client must not send a `Content-Type: application/xml` header when he wants to hit the method without the entity in the signature.

If another media type is already defined at the class level, annotate the method with `@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)`, see the example below.

```
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class myClass {

    @PUT
    @Path("/{p1}/something/{p2}/something/{p3}/something/{p4}")
    Response updateStuff(
                    @PathParam("p1") String p1,
                    @PathParam("p2") Long p2,
                    @PathParam("p3") String p3,
                    @PathParam("p4") Long p4,
                    MyEntity entity); 

    @PUT
    @Path("/{p1}/something/{p2}/something/{p3}/something/{p4}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    Response updateStuff(
                    @PathParam("p1") String p1,
                    @PathParam("p2") Long p2,
                    @PathParam("p3") String p3,
                    @PathParam("p4") Long p4); 
}
```